# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of null (Mootols)

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools

I want to implement a pop-up log-in form which can be seen on [this link](http://my-cravings.com/cravings-group-events-and-services-inquiry) (**close the pop-up and you can see on the left side of the page**).

It shows no error when you clicked the log-in. What I did was configured the login form to modal popup login. There is problem with mootools. My jQuery plugins works perfectly. I also tried putting `jQuery.noConflict();` to avoid conflict and still doesn't work.

What cause this? What will be the possible solution for this? Please help.. Im confused..

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle? that way we can help you understand and fix the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/webdevpao22/Lbwbr4up/ This is the code but it seems output wont appear on fiddle . I'm using RSFORM on joomla and integrate it with the form.. The only problem is that when i click the login the form shows error, the pop-up seems okay.. please check this link you can see the output  http://my-cravings.com/cravings-group-events-and-services-inquiry

Comment: you get this error on every page. unrelated - this is fx.slide / reveal joomla stuff.

Comment: What does it mean? Please help..